# Yii not able to save Image files CFileUploaded

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am not able to save the image uploaded from simple Form with this code

```
public function actionImage()
{
    print_r($_FILES);
    $dir = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');

    if(isset($_POST['img']))
    {
        $model = new FileUpload();
        $model->attributes = $_POST['img'];
        $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $model->image->saveAs($dir.'/'.$model->image->getName());
            // redirect to success page

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer my own question instead of using above code I used this:

```
public function actionImage()
{   
    $dir = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');
    if (isset($_FILES['img']))
    {   
        $image = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('img');
        $image->saveAs($dir.'/'.$image->getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: And how did you do the form? I tried: <?php echo CHtml::fileField('file','file'); ?> and the error is that no index found.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer my own question instead of using above code I used this:

```
 public function actionImage() {   
    $dir = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');
    if (isset($_FILES['img']))
    {   
        $image = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('img');
        $image->saveAs($dir.'/'.$image->getName());
    } }
```

Comment: please refer to this link for more examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092864/yii-file-upload-not-adding-to-database-using-form